# Binning of satellite Level 2 data

Tags: python, raster, remote-sensing, average

I can see that for the Aqua instruments (AIRS, MODIS, CERES etc), the Level 2 data are binned into Level 3 data providing average values for (say) a 1° x 1° cells grid.

Let's say that I would like to bin the data into a different size grid (e.g. 0.5° x 0.5°). I know that I could just write some code that takes Level 2 data as input and provides the binned data as output, but I wonder if there are tools that do this job.

I have found the [pymodis](http://www.pymodis.org/) python library and the [SeaDAS l2bin program](http://ocean.stanford.edu/research/seadas_doc/l2bin/l2bin.html) which might be useful but I'm not sure I'm on the right track.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are interested in this topic, [this document](http://ioccg.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ioccg-report-04.pdf) provides lots of information about different binning methods.

Other useful information are in the comments of [this github page](https://gist.github.com/loicdtx/8dfd69b0c5d09e13a6b5011b9aa10e9b) which contains very useful python implementations of L2 data binning.